# Unrelated packets in TCP communication capturing results

Tags: http, tcp, wireshark, packet-capture, pdu

I am using Wireshark to capture `TCP` communication packets in my experiment (using Mininet Simulation). The experiment involves a client (10.0.0.2) who requests `HTTP` page from the server (10.0.0.1). The following screenshot shows the capturing number **75** when the client sends HTTP GET and capturing number **89** when the server responds. Between them, I don't know what these packets are. Are they important in terms of TCP communication?

[image: Wireshark Capturing]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on what you are analyzing.  If you are concerned with the HTTP conversation then right click on one of the http rows and click- follow TCP stream.  This lets you see entire http session.  If you are having issues with the underlying TCP connection then those in-between rows become important.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can I ask what is the purpose of PDU packet? Is it another meaning of saying (packet payload) ?

Comment: I have had the same question in the past and have run across this post from wireshark:  https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/200805/msg00206.html